# Rails 5.2 Active Storage: How to determine and ensure that there are no floating blobs with direct uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

We recently upgraded our app to Rails 5.2 to make use of the active storage direct upload feature.

Following this [guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#integrating-with-libraries-or-frameworks) to integrate direct upload with our existing JS drag and drop, we've been able to get the upload working. We take the signed ID returned, and add it to hidden fields . Then on form submission, we create a new record and associate the blobs signed_id to create the association.

However, if the user doesn't go through with the form submission, is there a recommended way to ensure that the blobs/files without model associations get purged? The tricky part seems how to determine when to purge the blob.

Answer (score 2):

Purging process depends on you underlying storage, for example on S3 you can define object expiration policy for temporary blobs, on filesystem - periodically delete all files from temporary folder that are older than some limit.

As for temporary blob age that should be purged - this also depends on your application. Obviously it should be longer than user is filling the form plus some margin. If you do not have a problem with these lingering a bit longer - you can make the threshold somewhere around 24 hours or even more and purge once a day, so users will not encounter lost file for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the same questioning, and ended up concluding there is no ideal way: since it depends on the user **absence** of input, it is to be expected that the Blob can only be purged after a certain arbitrary timeout.

It can be a cron-like job for example.

Removing all dangling Blobs can be done through a one-liner though:

```rb
ActiveStorage::Blob.unattached.each(&:purge)
```

(Note: I spent quite some time on the MD5 computation too, if it's your case, take a look at the [blog article I posted on MD5 computation in javascript](https://dev.to/micmo/compute-md5-checksum-for-a-file-in-typescript-59a4))